# Call IncrementalLoading in ListView Windows Phone 8.1 RT App when user scrolls up

Tags: windows, listview, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In my app, I want a ListView where Items are loaded at bottom and as user scrolls 'up', ListView calls IncrementalLoading and load Items.

Comment: This answers your question + more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740079/wp-8-1-isupportincrementalloading-loadmoreitemsasync-keeps-getting-called-endles

Comment: LoadMoreItemsAsync is called while scrolling down. How can I call it while scrolling **up**.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here: [WP 8.1 bottom to top infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764868/wp-8-1-bottom-to-top-infinite-scrolling/32210157#32210157)

It's not an exact answer to your question (triggering incrementalloading) but instead uses the ExtendedListView (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedListView) to simulate the behavior by reversing the "refresh" (which you get by pulling/scrolling up at the top) with the loadmore behavior.

I hope this is helpful