# Telerik RadDataBoundListBox bottom to top scrolling

Tags: listview, telerik, infinite-scroll

I have explored [pull to refresh](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-8-xaml/databoundlistbox-pulltorefresh.html) behaviour of telerik control. But it doesn;t provide bottom to top incremental scrolling.

I want data to load incrementally but on scrolling upwards.

How can this be done?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764868/wp-8-1-bottom-to-top-infinite-scrolling?noredirect=1#comment48003599_29764868